# WPF Dependency Property - set from XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, dependency-properties

I am trying to achieve the following in a WPF personal finance app:

In various places I want to display a user control giving details of a asset holding (usually a share, bond etc), the target asset may be changed dynamically by the user in which case the control must be refreshed. Each Asset has a unique identifier, AssetId.

I am using MVVM and I've developed a single window with a View Model that takes AssetID as a parameter (property) and retrieves the relevant details for binding to the View. This work fine. What I'd like to do is make a generic user control with the same functionality so I can basically drop that 'window' inside other windows.

So I pretty much copy-pasted the XAML from that form into a User Control, where I'm struggling is passing in the AssetId from the parent window to the child control.

Google tells me I need a dependency property and here's where I am

```
Public Class HoldingView
    Private _AssetId As Integer
    Public AssetIdProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AssetId",
                                                                                      GetType(Integer),
                                                                                      GetType(HoldingView),
                                                                                      New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf AssetIDChanged)))
    Public Property AssetId As Integer
        Get
            Return GetValue(AssetIdProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            SetValue(AssetIdProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Sub AssetIDChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim NewAssetId As Integer
        NewAssetId = e.NewValue
        Me.DataContext.AssetId = NewAssetId
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.

        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = New HoldingViewmodel

    End Sub

End Class
```

Called like this:

```
<Grid>
    <local:HoldingView AssetId="{Binding AssetId}"/>
</Grid>
```

The code compiles and runs but when I try and load the window that has the user control, the app crashes with this message:

A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'AssetId' property of type 'HoldingView'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Which is not that helpful. From my Googling, you can also get this message if the syntax of the DP registration is not spot on, but it looks Ok to my inexperienced eye...

Anybody else had this?

Answer (score 2):

```
Public AssetIdProperty As DependencyProperty
```

should be

```
Public Shared ReadOnly AssetIdProperty As DependencyProperty
```

Please take a look at [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties).

Also remove

```
Me.DataContext = New HoldingViewmodel
```

because that will effectively break any DataContext-based Bindings like

```
AssetId="{Binding AssetId}"
```

where the source property is supposed to be owned by the object in the inherited DataContext, which usually is an object in the application's view model.

Controls should never have their own, "private" view model, but instead handle property changes in code behind. In case of UserControls, there could simply be UI elements in their XAML that would be bound to the UserConrol's own properties.

Hence

```
Me.DataContext.AssetId = NewAssetId
```

in the PropertyChangedCallback is pointless and should be removed, as well as

```
Private _AssetId As Integer
```

To summarize, it should look like this:

```
Public Class HoldingView
    Public Shared ReadOnly AssetIdProperty As DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AssetId",
            GetType(Integer),
            GetType(HoldingView),
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf AssetIdPropertyChanged)))

    Public Property AssetId As Integer
        Get
            Return GetValue(AssetIdProperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            SetValue(AssetIdProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared Sub AssetIdPropertyChanged(
        d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        CType(d, HoldingView).AssetIdChanged(e.NewValue)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AssetIdChanged(id As Integer)
        ...
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yaaay! That worked like a dream. Many thanks.

So having re-educated myself to remove (nearly) all code from the code-behind, I now put it back. It took some thinking about but it all fell into place eventually.

Thanks again Clemens. You're a great example of what this site is all about.